# Check if image has vector paths with imageMagick (not only clipping paths)

Tags: path, imagemagick, command-line-interface

I found this to check if image has clipping path : 
http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=22044

```js
identify -verbose "$infile" | grep "Clipping path:"
```

However some images can contain vector paths but because they are not set as clipping path, the former command "fails". As a matter of fact, I end up with false negative.

I have found everywhere but couldn't find any instructions to check at any existing path regardless of if there are clipping path or not. Is it a deadend ?

I put a download link for demoing such a file : http://dl.free.fr/o4WfEpCQR

Comment: Clipping paths can also be in the 8bim profile. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#clip

Comment: Thanks a lot. I saw that but when I execute the command, I get this error message : identify: unknown image property "%[8BIM:1999,2998:#1]" @ warning/property.c/InterpretImageProperties/3599.
I am presuming this i sbecause I use this agains a jpg file while doc claims it's for tiff.

Comment: Does the JPG show an 8bim when doing identify -verbose on it? If not, then that would be the case. Not all vector paths are readily available. Some are hidden in proprietary locations. The only places that I know ImageMagick can extract them are from the identify -verbose for an SVG clipping path or in the 8bim profile. There may be others for which I am unaware.

Comment: Thanks @fmw42 It's likely related indeed. I can see this piece of data: "Profile-8bim: 5118 bytes" yet no clipping path defined in the verbose text. I also checked with a known for certain file with no opaths at all and the "Profile-8bim: …" doesn't appear. Would you think it would mean a path if present even if not set as clipping path ?

Comment: I am not an expert on PSD files. However, I looked at your file in Photoshop and it seems to has a path. But I do not think it is a clipping path. It looks like a simple draw path. If you want further information regarding clipping paths in ImageMagick, then I suggest you post to the ImageMagick Discourse server forum at https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/. Note that Photoshop is notorious for hiding information in strange places that may not always be easily accessed. Your  file has 8bim, psd:additional-info, and xmp profiles. The path may be in any of these.

Comment: Indeed there is this path. Client wants to sort files with paths hence the question. Also asked in IM forums. will let everyone know here if there is any improvements.

Comment: It is not a clipping path as far as I can tell. Just a drawn vector circle. Am I wrong? I do not see any clipping to remove the background when I enable that path. I do not know where PS stores paths, whether clipping or not. I would suggest consulting the PSD documentation